# Create array of files and sort by date in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, file, sorting

I have an array of filenames, is there any way to sort these files by modification date?

Comment: There are two modification times available to you. `File.mtime` vs. `File.ctime`, with a subtle difference between the two.

Comment: @theTinMan: `File.ctime` refers to the time the file was created, not modified.

Comment: Absolutely not. `"Returns the change time for the named file (the time at which directory information about the file was changed, not the file itself)."` Only Windows supports file creation date.  *nix only understands the modification times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `sort_by` method in conjunction with `File.mtime` method, which returns the last modification time of the given file.

```
filenames.sort_by {|filename| File.mtime(filename) }
```

Comment: Note that `sort_by` does not modify the receiver, but instead returns a new array, so you'll want to either use the result directly (e.g. `names.sort_by{ ... }.each{ ... }`) or save the result (e.g. `sorted = names.sort_by{ ... }`). Ruby 1.9.2 has added `sort_by!` to modify the array in-place, however.